# OpenBLASはスレッドセーフですか？

Tags: c++, c, 行列

OpenBLASはスレッドセーフですか？
例えば、sgemm関数を複数のスレッドから利用しても問題ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq#multi-threaded
によると No です。

正確に言うと、並列化 (=マルチスレッド) を OpenMP のみで利用している場合に限り Yes (OpenBLAS の専用ビルドが必要) 自前でマルチスレッド機能を実装しているプログラムから OpenBLAS を使う場合はダメ。

GPU 実装だったりするとそもそもマルチスレッドにする意味がないですしね (GPU 資源は１つしかないので)